# Error convert value for unicode - databrick notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks

Create function in Databricks Notebook to remove accents from words

```
import unicodedata
import sys

from pyspark.sql.functions import translate, regexp_replace

def make_trans():
    matching_string = ""
    replace_string = ""

    for i in range(ord(" "), sys.maxunicode):
        name = unicodedata.name(chr(i), "")
        if "WITH" in name:
            try:
                base = unicodedata.lookup(name.split(" WITH")[0])
                matching_string += chr(i)
                replace_string += base
            except KeyError:
                pass

    return matching_string, replace_string

def clean_text(c):
    matching_string, replace_string = make_trans()
    return translate(
        regexp_replace(c, "\p{M}", ""), 
        matching_string, replace_string
    ).alias(c)
```

But I am not able to change the value in the dataframe, if I execute the command as select it works, but when I apply this command the following error occurs

```
Command error: df['productName'] = clean_text(df['productName'])

TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

This command execute with sucess

```
df.select(clean_text("productName"))
```

Do I have to loop one line at a time? Is this correct way to work with spark + databricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframes are immutable so you cannot change the value. You can however add a new column. So in your case:

```
df = df.withColumn("cleanProductName", clean_text(df['productName']))
```

That "feels" like duplication at first. But remember the dataframe is immutable so is always the same size. Think of it as a View in a SQL database. Hence the Select works.

If you really want you can drop the old column from the dataframe. But unless you actually use the column (select * from example) it will make no difference to the overall performance.